# Adding date from 3 columns in table X to one column in table Y

Tags: sqlite

Hi I am new to sqlite and I am wondering if it is possible to add date from 3 columns in table X to one column in table Y. For example, in Table X, I have 3 columns called startDay,startMonth,startYear. I want to add these to one column in table Y called Start_Date (possible in format DD/MM/YYYY). Also hopefully the format it is in should be able to carry out computation, i.e subtracting 2 dates. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "add date" here?  Can you give three date value and then show us what the output is?

Comment: so for example in tableX there are 3 columns:
startDay column will have something like (23, 09, 17....)
startMonth column similarly will have in each row (04, 07, 11,...)
startYear column (2000, 2011, 2017,...)

So i want to reproduce this in table Y for eaxmple the first row entry in the format (23/04/2000)

Comment: I seriously recommend _against_ storing the year, month, and day components of your dates separately.  Doing this will only make working with your dates a nightmare.  Just store a single date for each date.

Comment: Its taken from a excel file I have downloaded which I have imported into sqlite. I want to make one column that represents the date.

Comment: Believe it or not, I might actually suggest that you convert to date within Excel, before you bring the data in SQLite.

Comment: Alright so I am guessing its easier to do this in excel than in sqlite. Thanks

Comment: You _can_ handle this from SQLite, but you should realize that SQLite does not actually have an actual date type.  Dates are just plain text under the hood, so SQLite does not have the robust date function support which something like Oracle or SQL Server would have.  I vote for letting Excel do the date heavy lifting in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable(start_date TEXT);
INSERT INTO newtable
  SELECT printf('%d-%02d-%02d', startYear, startMonth, startDay)
  FROM oldtable;
```

And to compute the number of days between two dates:

```
SELECT juliandate('2019-06-30') - juliandate('2019-06-29') AS diff;
diff      
----------
1.0
```

(Using a format other than those supported by sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) like your `dd/mm/yyyy` is a bad idea. Means you can't use them with the functions, and in your case, also means you can't meaningfully sort by date)